# Substitute local javascript variable's value into Pug's interpolation

Tags: javascript, pug

I am new to pug and now I am trying to render a html view which contains a table whose entries are parsed from `app.js`

this is my `index.pug`

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        title Pug
    body
        table
            - var columns = ['apple', 'pine', 'peach'];
            tr
                each column in columns
                    th #{column}
            - for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                tr 
                    each column in columns 
                        td #{data[i].column}
```

here is my `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const pug = require('pug')
var app = module.exports = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

var foo = [{
        apple: 1,
        pine: 2,
        peach: 3
    }, {
        apple: 4,
        pine: 5,
        peach: 6
    },
    {
        apple: 7,
        pine: 8,
        peach: 9
    }
];
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        data: foo
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listen to port 3000 now'));
```

I am not sure how should I do the following trick: inside `index.pug` I do declare a local js array of three possible values `apple`, `pine` and `peach`, and I am use a for-each loop to iterate over this array. 
However, in the last line of pug, it seems like that pug doesn't substitute the "column" in `#{data[i].column}` with `apple`, `pine` and `peach` as the loop is iterating over.

So is there a way to tell pug to replace `column` in `#{data[i].column}` with the values of same local js variable that I have declared?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your local variable value and server side variable value is same using if statement and based on that you can give the value to `td` of local variable `column`

```
table
        - var columns = ['apple', 'pine', 'peach'];
        tr
            each column in columns
                th #{column}
        - for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            tr 
                each column in columns
                    if column == data[i].column
                        td column
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. What I want is to substitute the `column` keyword in #{data[i].column} with three different values `apple`, `peach`, `pine` so it becomes `#{data[i].apple}` `{data[i].pine}` and `{data[i].peach}` so pug can put each value respective to the key `apple`, `peach` and `pine` from each `data` object when this page is rendering

Comment: I am confused, can you please explain me by changing server side and client side values and what should be the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
html(lang='en')
    head
        title Pug
    body
        table
            - var columns = ['apple', 'pine', 'peach'];
            //- - var columns = Object.keys(data[0]); // Could also use this
            tr
                each column in columns
                    th=column
            - for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                tr 
                    each column in columns
                        td=data[i][column]
```